# Reference external dll in MVC 4 Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dll

I have a MVC 4 application, where I would like to call my external DLL (.net project as well) which will return me a dataset. I just can't get it working in my project though I have reference it. The DLL project name is PScope.Optimizer. It gives me error - **0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'PScope' is undefined**

This is sample code from the DLL :

```
Public Class Main
Public Sub Main(connString As String, tenantID As Int16)
    Connection_String = connString
    Tenant_ID = tenantID
End Sub
Public Function MyFunc() As Integer

    Return 0
End Function
```

End Class

This is code from MVC :

```
    @using PScope.Optimizer;

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <script " type="text/javascript">
        function OnButtonClick(s, e) {
            var main1 = new PScope.Optimizer.Main();
        }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

       @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
   {
       settings.Name = "Button";
       settings.Text = "Run Optimiser";
       settings.ToolTip = "This may take a while. Please be patient";
       settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function (s, e) { OnButtonClick(s, e); }";
       //settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;

   }).GetHtml()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is MVC, right? As in Model, View, Controller? Then, If your DLL return a dataset, why would it have anything to do with the View? Should not it be in a Model, or ModelView eventually, and called by the controller? Your javascript code should just call a method in the controller.

looks to me like you are trying to shortcut the controller.

It seems you are wanting to mix server and client code in the view, but to me the only benefit you are going to get from defeating the very purpose of MVC is to loose a clean separation of concerns brought by MVC. it's not because something is possible that it should be done.....

Comment: Hi Bernard, true when I started had no clear picture on how this should work. Now I understand MVC better. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to run the C# code as JavaScript.

Try something like this:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
```

Comment: Its not the 'proper' way, but it is what he wanted and answered his question.

Comment: Is this even possible in mvc? What would this do..? Is it like the equivalent of `@{...}` syntax or...? I'm so confused right now.